# Year 0 gets corrupted

Tags: datetime, php-5.2

```
$datetime = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
$date_string = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');//-0001-11-30 00:00:00
```

date gets turned from 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to -0001-11-30 00:00:00 
this is obviously wrong, why does this happen, how to fix it?
Should at least return false.

info:
PHP Version 5.2.13-0.dotdeb.1
Linux 2.6.26-2-openvz-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 25 05:14:47 UTC 2010 x86_64

Comment: There is no "year 0" in many calendar systems, especially the Julian/Gregorian, of which some variant is being used by `format` I imagine. It's curious why it chooses that date, however... 30 days "too early"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sort of correct by definition:

- the zero-th day as opposed to the first yields a (hypothetical) minus one day
- the zero-th month as opposed to the first yields a (hypothetical) minus one month

Take the (hypothetical) 1st of Jan in the year 0, subtract a month -> 1st of Dec in the year -1.
Subtract a day -> 30th of Nov in the year -1

Alternatively, they could have chosen to fix up the day first, then it'd go like:
1 Jan minus 1d -> 31st of Dec -0001,  minus 1mo -> 30th of Nov -0001

The formatter obviously does the bound check to only produce valid dates.  (For some definition of ``valid'')

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (although I would prefer php to just return false), some weird programmer filled my database with these dates, and for a moment there I forgot that there was no such thing as day 0, or month 0. Guess I got too used to counting from 0. At least now I learned something new about how php treats dates. :P

Comment: Hehe, well, interestingly sql '92 *allows* the zero-th month and day, and I guess that's where a lot of confusion is coming from.